# Navigation bar and image on the same line

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have aligned right by image, but now I want to put the image that was aligned right on the same bar/line as my navigation bar.
CSS code, section for navigation bar:

```
body {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: lightblue; 
    color: #696969;
    padding: 3px;
}

#main {
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left:  15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #cc9900;
    color: #996600;
    font-size: 30px;
}

table {
    width:100%;
}

table, th , td {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {
    text-align: left; 
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

ul#menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
}

ul#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 2px;
}

ul#menu li a {
    background-color: orange;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}

ul#menu li a:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
}

table {
    width:100%;
}

table, th , td {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {
    text-align: left; 
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>X-treme FreeRoam</title>
  <link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<nav id="nav01"></nav><img src="images/title.png" width="386px" height="56px" align="right">

<div id="main">
  <center><div id=”header”><img src="images/MyBB Logo 3.png" style="width:970px;height:280px"></div></center>
  <h1><center><b>Welcome to X-treme FreeRoam's website</b></center></h1>

  <p><center>Welcome to X-treme FreeRoam's website, we setup a forum website for players from X-treme FreeRoam server in Grand Theft Auto San Andreas Multiplayer to communicate and voice their feedback and improvements for the server. This page is the homepage of our server. You can talk about other things unrelated to Grand Theft Auto on the Unrelated topic under the Other forum by clicking on the Forum tab in the navigation bar. Please do look around.</center></p>

</div>

<footer id="foot01"></footer>

<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Note that my nav01 and foot01 comes from the same javascript I created**

Comment: Note: `<center>` has been deprecated and should no longer be used.

Comment: `float: left;` for your `#nav01` would help you [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/y6xmya2k/)

Comment: @Paulie_D which <center> do you mean?

Comment: @fcastillo where do I add the float: left;

Comment: To `#nav01` tag. Here you have an [example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/y6xmya2k/1/)

Comment: @RichardPrime You have a `<center>` tag inside the paragraph tag...that "element" is no longer valid HTML..other means of centering are now used.

Comment: @fcastillo your help in the example link helped me greatly thanks!